# How to use OHAI attributes within a chef role that is defined in JSON format?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I want to know what is the correct way to assign `node['ipaddress']` OHAI attribute within the chef role. My chef role is defined in the `JSON format`.

```
{  
  "name": "temp_role",  
  "description": "This is temp role",  
  "json_class": "Chef::Role",  
  "default_attributes": {  
"client_addr": #{node['ipaddress']}  
  },  
  "override_attributes": {  
  },    
  "chef_type": "role",  
  "run_list": [  
   "recipe[test::prereq]"  
  ],  
  "env_run_lists": {  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use ohai data in roles, JSON format or otherwise. Roles are purely static data, converted to JSON during upload even if they are using the `.rb` DSL. anything dynamic must live in a cookbook, in this case probably a role-pattern cookbook.

Comment: How can i use a role-pattern cookbook to solve my problem?

Comment: You would write one. Describing the full process is out of scope for SO.

Comment: The given link by @Tensibai is no more available/invalid